# Web Audio getUserMedia constraints have no effect

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have some Javascript that outputs an input stream (from a mic or something else) with some AudioNodes inbetween back to the default output but I'm having trouble with a large amount of latency.
To be a bit more precise, I've connected my guitar to a Behringer UCG102 USB Interface, and I've captured the stream of that device on a simple web page that displays the waveform of the input.

```
var constraints = {
  audio: {
    deviceId: selectedDevice.deviceId,
    sampleSize: 16,
    sampleRate: 16000,
    latency: 4
  }
};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(stream) {
  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
  var compressor = audioCtx.createDynamicsCompressor();
  compressor.threshold.value = -50;
  compressor.knee.value = 40;
  compressor.ratio.value = 12;
  compressor.attack.value = 0;
  compressor.release.value = 0.25;
  source.connect(compressor);

  // debug audio analyser created here
  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  compressor.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(gainNode);
  analyser.fftSize = 2048;
  var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

  // Drawing the analyser code was here...

  gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
});
```

As you can see I have created a 'constraints' variable that defines some audio settings, but except for the deviceId property it seems to not change anything. Even if I set `{audio: {volume: 0}}` I get the same sound output.

I've been reading the MDN documentation about MediaStreamConstraints and such but cannot figure out why I can't seem to control volume, latency,...

Comment: You're asking for a latency of 4 seconds, which is extremely long and unusual.  Also, the sample rate of 16 kHz is very low.  Not all browsers/devices will support these constraints.  Your code should make no assumptions on the result.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

the constraints you specified may be either not handled by your browser, or changed by the system since values are interpreted by default as `ideal`.

**Long answer:**

Constraints accepted by `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` are discussed [here (check here also the browser compatibility)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints). The value of each constraint can be specified as `min`, `max`, `exact`, or `ideal` (which is the default), as discussed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints).

"Constraints which are specified using any or all of `max`, `min`, or `exact` are always treated as mandatory. If any constraint which uses one or more of those can't be met [...], the promise will be rejected.".

A constraint specified as `ideal` (remember this is the default!) can be adjusted by the system, resulting in a value which differs from the value you requested.